# Drawing a Venn diagram with shaded area and annotation

Tags: diagrams

How can i drawing a picture like this, I tried, but I failed. I'm thinking use this code but I did get the picture I want. Thank you so much! Liang

```
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \draw (1.5,-0.7) circle (1.1) node[below=10mm]{$A$}; 
                \draw (3.9,-2.4) rectangle (-1,1); 
                \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use better coordinates for the points if you use the origin to be the center of the circle.

Comment: @Liang: Please choose better titles for your future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to get something similar to the desired picture. Of course, there are many possible ways to improve it, e.g. by following @Sigur's advice and so on. But to first approximation I'd just fill the rectangle with a pattern and then the circle white.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[pattern=north west lines] (3.9,-2.4) rectangle (-1,1); 
  \node[circle,draw,fill=white,minimum size=2cm] at (1.5,-0.7) {$A$}; 
  \node at (3.2,-1.5) {$A^c$}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]